# Sprinkle blood 7 times in front of the veil

Tags: contradiction, leviticus, offering

In Leviticus 4:5-7 (NASB)

> 5 Then the anointed priest is to take some of the blood of the bull and bring it to the tent of meeting, 6 and the priest shall dip his finger in the blood and sprinkle some of the blood seven times before the Lord, in front of the veil of the sanctuary. 7 The priest shall also put some of the blood on the horns of the altar of fragrant incense which is before the Lord in the tent of meeting; and all the rest of the blood of the bull he shall pour out at the base of the altar of burnt offering, which is at the doorway of the tent of meeting.

we read that the priest shall

1. Take some blood of the bull to the tent of meeting
2. Dip his finger in the blood
3. Sprinkle some of it 7 times in front of the veil of the sanctuary
4. Put blood on the horns of the altar
5. Put the rest of the blood at the base of the altar.

Then, in Leviticus 9:8-9 (NASB)

> 8 So Aaron came near to the altar and slaughtered the calf of the sin offering which was for himself. 9 Aaron’s sons then presented the blood to him; and he dipped his finger in the blood and put some on the horns of the altar, and poured out the rest of the blood at the base of the altar.

we read that Aaron

1. Slaughtered the calf near the altar
2. Dipped his finger in the blood
3. Put blood on the horns of the altar
4. Put the rest of the blood at the base of the altar.

Basically between the two passages the step "Sprinkle some of it 7 times in front of the veil of the sanctuary" doesn't appear in Leviticus 9.

What's the reason behind this difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite uncomplicated.

**Lev 4**

In Leviticus 4 we have the instructions for (V2)

> one who sins unintentionally against any of the LORD’s commandments
> and does what is forbidden by them

**Lev 9**

By contrast, Leviticus 9 is part of the narrative in Lev 8 & 9 which describes the ordination/initiation/consecration of the High priesthood of Aaron.

Thus, the two rites were for slightly different functions - one a sin offering and the other part of the ordination service.  While the ordination service had an atonement component (with two sacrifices not one, Lev 9:8 & 12), that was not its primary focus.