Why didn’t ruler have to sprinkle blood on the veil
In Leviticus 4:22-35 there is no mention of having to sprinkle blood on the veil as written in Leviticus 4:6 and Leviticus 4:17. The priest when sinning brings guilt upon the people from what I understand in Leviticus 4:3. Now I understand why God commands them both to sprinkle it on the vail but what I don’t understand is why then when the ruler or an individual sinned, why they didn’t have to sprinkle it on the veil?

Do you mean sprinkling blood in FRONT of the veil? Related question and answer here: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/55315/sprinkle-blood-7-times-in-front-of-the-veil?rq=1

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics. To help you understand how this site works, please take our Tour: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
